# How use gnu-make to compile files to a directory path which is result after taking the input-directory and apply multiple string substitutions on it?

Tags: gnu-make

Let's say that I have some source files in some "input"-directories that I want to compile and put in different "output"-directories. To compute the output-directories, all you have to do is to take the input-directories and replace `src` with `obj` and `x/y/x` with `u/v/w` (double string substitution).

For example:

```
g++ -c src/a/x/y/z/b/c/file1.cpp -o obj/a/u/v/w/b/c/file1.o
g++ -c src/a/x/y/z/b/c/file2.cpp -o obj/a/u/v/w/b/c/file2.o
g++ -c src/b/x/y/z/c/d/file3.cpp -o obj/b/u/v/w/c/d/file3.o
```

Now to my question:

I know that you can use % to make a single string substitution on a "stem" in GNU Make, but what if you had to do multiple substitutions? How would you do that?

Possible GNU Makefile:

```
found_files := $(shell find src -type f -name '*.cpp')
all: $(found_files)
obj/%/x/y/z/%.o: src/%/u/v/w/%.cpp   <---- GNU Make will not let me use multiple % here
      $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem to which this seems to be the solution?

Comment: Yes, I have a concrete problem to which this seem to be the solution. Exactly why I have this problem is hard to explain without boring you with too many uninteresting details.

I work with a product. While its production code is built using cmake, the test code is built using gnu make. I only have control of the gnu make build system.

Part of building the production code is to generate some code. Unfortunately cmake adds "CMakeFiles" (comparable with x/y/z) to the generated code path which I want to remove. Its just easier to include generated header files if the include path is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, one %-wildcard per pattern-rule is all you get. In your
scenario therefore, no pattern rule can express the mapping from your `.cpp`s to
your `.o`s and you must define the compile recipe distinctly for each
`.cpp` -> `.o` pair. You can get `make` to generate all those recipes like
so:

**Makefile**

```
src2obj = $(subst x/y/z,u/v/w,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(patsubst src/%,obj/%,$(1))))

define compile =
$(call src2obj,$(1)): $(1)
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $$@ $$< 
endef

srcs := $(shell find src -type f -name '*.cpp')
objs := $(foreach src,$(srcs),$(call src2obj,$(src)))

.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

prog: $(objs)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) 

$(foreach src,$(srcs),$(eval $(call compile,$(src))))


clean:
    rm -f $(objs) prog
```

If I set up a "Hello world" example of your scenario, this makefile gives:

```
make && ./prog
g++   -c -o obj/b/u/v/w/c/d/file3.o src/b/x/y/z/c/d/file3.cpp 
g++   -c -o obj/a/u/v/w/b/c/file1.o src/a/x/y/z/b/c/file1.cpp 
g++   -c -o obj/a/u/v/w/b/c/file2.o src/a/x/y/z/b/c/file2.cpp 
g++ -o prog obj/b/u/v/w/c/d/file3.o obj/a/u/v/w/b/c/file1.o obj/a/u/v/w/b/c/file2.o   
Hello World
```

However, I'd look earnestly for any reasonable refactoring of the build tree
that would let me avoid such prickly make code as this.